# Can the IC-R6 scanner receive NFM

Tags: receiver, fm

I am considering purchasing the Icom IC-R6. One of the determining factors, and my questions is, can it can receive [FMN](http://www.radioreference.com/apps/db/?ctid=442#cid-15933) (I believe that is narrowband FM)?

Answer (score 2):

From the [ICOM IC-R6 specifications](http://www.icomamerica.com/en/products/receivers/handheld/r6/specifications.aspx):

> Mode: AM, FM, WFM

"FMN" is indeed short for "Narrowband FM", so this scanner, which receives "FM and WFM", will pick up such a station perfectly fine. (WFM here stands for "Wideband FM", which is typically used by commercial broadcast radio.)

Comment: Note that in amateur radio, "FM" is commonly used to describe 25 kHz channel width FM, whereas "NFM" or "FMN" is likewise used to describe 12.5 kHz channel width FM. WFM is indeed used to describe "broadcast" FM, which is what, 150 kHz channel width? Given that the IC-R6 allows tuning steps all the way down to 5 kHz, including 6.25 and 12.5 kHz, it should be suitable for what the OP wants.